# Energy drain in damped oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

Suppose we have a mass on a spring with a damping term. The equation of motion is given by:

$$m \ddot{x} = -kx - c\dot{x}$$

I believe solutions are damped oscillations of the form:

$$x = x_0 e^{-\alpha t}\cos{\omega t}$$

where $x_0$ is the initial extension of the mass.

I am interested in calculating the total energy taken out of the system by the damping term $F_{damp}=-c\dot{x}$:

$$E_{out}=\int_0^\infty F_{damp}(t)v(t) dt$$

$$E_{out}=\int_0^\infty -c \dot{x}\ \dot{x}\ dt$$

Would one expect this energy to always exactly balance the $1/2 k x_0^2$ that we put into the system initially?

Comment: You solution is not complete - you need also an initial condition for $\dot{x}(0)$, and there are *two* linearly independent solutions for a second-order differential equation. See, e.g. [Wikipedia on linear damping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping#Linear_damping). Also, yes, one would of course expect total energy to be conserved - if you actually calculate $E_\text{out}$, you will find that it indeed is.

Comment: Your balance should be $\frac{1}{2} k x_0^2 + E_{out} = 0$ with the solution of $k=m (\alpha^2+\omega^2)$

Answer (score 1):

The damping introduces a dissipative element to the system, that is, energy is leaving the spring-mass system with time. As such, the energy is not conserved.

The maximum energy for the system occurs at its initial configuration; the spring is stretched to some extent $A$ (initial amplitude). The initial energy for the spring is thus purely of a potential nature. Now, recall that the potential energy of this system can be written
\begin{equation*}
E_{\text{total}}=U(A)=\frac{1}{2}kA^{2}
\end{equation*}
where $A$ is the initial amplitude. You have yourself supplied the time-evolution of the system, $x=x(t)$, which incorporates the amplitude. However, due to this damping the amplitude is time-dependant and we have
\begin{equation*}
A(t)=x_{0}e^{-\alpha t}
\end{equation*}
thus resulting in
\begin{equation*}
E_{\text{total}}(t)=\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}_{0}e^{-2\alpha t}
\end{equation*}
which is an explicit expression of the energy in the spring-mass system at times $t$. With this, we can write the energy lost to the environment (due to the damping friction) as
\begin{equation*}
E_{\text{out}}(t)\equiv E_{\text{total}}(t=0) - E_{\text{total}}(t) = \frac{1}{2}kx^{2}_{0}(1-e^{-2\alpha t})
\end{equation*}

**Edit:**  What you mean by ''balance the initial energy $\frac{1}{2}kx^{2}_{0}$'' is to me unclear. But I believe that you may find the answer to that last question of yours by considering my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Would one expect this energy to equal the $1/2 kx_0^2$ that we put into the system initially?

**Yes, it must.**

Energy conservation applies between any two points in time. If your point one is the initially stretched out spring before it is let go with energy $U_{el}=\frac{1}{2}kx_0^2$ and your point two is the situation of no energy stored in the spring anymore $U_{el}=0$, then:

$$\sum E_{total,1}=\sum E_{total,2} \Rightarrow \\ U_{el,1}=U_{el,2}+Q \Rightarrow \\ \frac{1}{2}kx_0^2=Q_{damping}$$

Where $Q$ is heat or work done causing damping.

Comment: Ok - so I just need to do the maths to verify that fact.

Comment: @JohnEastmond No need to verify. This is true. (Unless you have other forces interacting dragging out or adding energy.) Energy conservation is a law of nature. when you calculate the left side, you have the value of all energy dissipated, which I called $Q_{damping}$ here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to check that your formula for $E_{out}$ is correct and you do not even need an explicit solution to the differential equation:

If the formula is correct, then it must hold due to the conservation of the total energy that $E_{kin} + E_{pot} - E_{out} = \text{const}$. So we plug in your formula and check via differentiation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}\left( \frac12 m \dot{x}(t)^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx(t)^2 + c\int_0^t \dot{x}(t)^2\right) 
&= m {\dot x}(t){\ddot x}(t) + kx(t){\dot x}(t)+c{\dot x}(t)^{2} \\
&= {\dot x}(t)\bigl(-kx(t)-c{\dot x}(t)\bigr) + kx(t){\dot x}(t)+c{\dot x}(t)^{2}\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
where we have used the differential equation itself to arrive from the first to the second line.